# How can we define role in boonex

Tags: boonex-dolphin

I want to create 2 more roles in boonex except (admin and normal user) and want to manage privacy setting and accessabilty of site according to role.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Go to  Admin panel> Tools> Membership Settings> 
There you can create new membership level, set privacy for each level.
You will need to check page access module to ensure that they have access to each page in Navigation menu.
Also if you uninstall a module for an update, you will need to check membership settings for the memberships that are create again. 
If you want to assign Admin duties, download deanos Tool, which is free in Boonex market.
If you are assigning Moderator duties that will be done on that groups page, manage fans in action block